# Matplotlib scatterplot : Open image corresponding to point which i click

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a simple matplotlib code where i am generating scatterplot. Now i want to open image corresponding to the point when i click on that point. For example when i click on point one it should open image one, for point two it should open image two. Here is my code,

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,4,9,16]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,'o')
coords = []

def onclick(event):
  global ix, iy
  ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
  print 'x = %f, y = %f'%(ix, iy)

  global coords
  coords.append((ix, iy))
  print len(coords)
  z=len(coords)-1
  print coords[z][1]
  per = (10*coords[z][1])/100
  errp = abs(coords[z][1]+per)
  errn = abs(coords[z][1]-per)
  print "errn=%f, errp=%f"%(errn, errp)

  for i in range(len(x)):
    if abs(float(y[i])) >= errn and abs(float(y[i])) <= errp :
      print y[i]
      fig2 = plt.figure()
      img=mpimg.imread('white.png')
      line2 = plt.imshow(img)
      fig2.show()
  return coords

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Now the problem here is when i zoom in a plot where y values very high (Of the order of 10^3 it is opening image even if i click far away from the point.

How i can get required image when clicked on point itself rather somewhere in nearby region?

[If this is duplicate question please give me a link to the original question]

edit : forgot to add image [white.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn5wK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to work while zooming, I would make the distance within which a click has to occur a function of the axis limits:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,4,9,16]

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'o')

def onclick(event):
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print("I clicked at x={0:5.2f}, y={1:5.2f}".format(ix,iy))

    # Calculate, based on the axis extent, a reasonable distance 
    # from the actual point in which the click has to occur (in this case 5%)
    ax = plt.gca()
    dx = 0.05 * (ax.get_xlim()[1] - ax.get_xlim()[0])
    dy = 0.05 * (ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0])

    # Check for every point if the click was close enough:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if(x[i] > ix-dx and x[i] < ix+dx and y[i] > iy-dy and y[i] < iy+dy):
            print("You clicked close enough!")

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Bart thanks for the solution, this is working great. If necessary i will add working solution here.